# Confusing error when attempting to start the Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The following output appeared when I was attempting to start an instance of the Jupyter botebook:

```
C:\Users\CaitlinG>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py",
line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py",
line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\CaitlinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\jupyter
-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 31, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packag
es\zmq\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled[0])
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\ctypes\__in
it__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\users\caitling\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\ctypes\__in
it__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.5.2. I installed the package, along with its dependencies, via: pip3 install "ipython[notebook]" --upgrade

The aforementioned process proceeded without incident but I am confused why the issue has appeared.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with pyzmq 15.3. Installing a previous version worked for me:

```
pip install pyzmq==15.2
```

See:
https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/62

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.